# Engineering Ph.D. from another country searching TT position in US

Tags: tenure-track

I had my complete education up to Ph.D. in Engineering in a country on the other side of the planet. However, I did a postdoc at a tier 1 US university for two years and then went back to my country, worked in a reputed multi-national company for 6 years. I had 6 publications in top journals with my advisers. More importantly (I believe), in the last four years, I published on my own (as the corresponding author) 6 more papers in top most journals (considered rank 1, 2, and 3) in my field. I am writing 4 more papers at present. I left my industry job, as I am interested in doing research in academic setting. Therefore, I came back to the US on another postdoc position. I am tempted to try my luck, applying to TT positions here, but, not sure about my chances. Another fact, I think, is against me is that I am in early 40's. Could any one let me know if I stand a chance here for a TT job?

Comment: Apply and find out...

Comment: You age itself isn't an issue but the number of years it took you to produce that CV is how it matters. Overall it seems like your publication output is about average for a postdoc. Is average good enough for an academic job in your field?

Comment: Age is not an issue especially since you have been working and are productive. However, it sounds like you should be networking and getting in contact with potential colleagues and institutions.  Whether you would enjoy teaching and be able to teach well is the other issue for a TT (tenure track) position.